# Grouping by week and daily breakdowns in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query concerning SSRS and displaying data. My report will consist of a weekly breakdown of week numbers and sum of hours. Showing something like this

12/06/10   351

19/06/10   342

26/06/10   399

And then on clicking/toggling the week data cell(s) a breakdown by day will be displayed. I have completed the daily breakdown and written a function to return all weeks in 2010 but my difficulty lies in grouping by the week.

In the layout tab for SSRS, I have created a group on the week value and date value, and have the week value appearing in the group cell, but it creates an additional blank line below each day breakdown.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks very much

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?  Also could you provide a screenshot and possibly what the dataset looks like?

Comment: To me in sounds like you've got 2 group rows, one for the week and one for the day, and then the details row, but you have all of your data on the row for the day.  It's hard to figure out though without any screen shots.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'm using SSRS 2005. I have two group rows for day and week as it's the only way it looks slightly ordered. The dataset i started with was the daily breakdown as pre-mentioned and then written a function to return the weeks which I left outer joined with the day data. If grouped by two rows as it was the only way to make the dataset resemble the results that I wanted. Sorry I cannot provide screenshots at this moment in time.

Comment: Could you maybe do a excel table that resembles what you are trying to do? I think you might be wanting to use Column Groups rather than row groups.

Comment: The next comment provides a link to some screenshots which outline the problem a little more. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackscreens.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/screenshots/